# Database design to track updates since last visit

Tags: database-design

I am designing database for a Forum kind of application. The use cases involves showing unread topics for an user. So, I require to keep track of read/unread status for each post for each user id.

I have users and posts table. I am thinking I should created 'Read_Posts' table with userid and postid, so I can add each post user has seen to this table. But, over time this table will become very huge.

Any other alternate approaches to this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can create table containing post_id and another column which contains comma separated string of userid. This way you can at least minimize the number of rows in table.

Comment: @Harry - and increase the the complexity of the queries. Not to mention making them much more expensive.

Comment: @Oded: It will not increase query complexity. Just increase complexity of the coding logic to operate on data. And as per i think its not tough job to get array of id from comma separated string. It also help in query in which we write "where user_id in ('here we can directly get comma separated string')".

Comment: @Harry - So, if you want a list of posts that have been read by user X?

Comment: @Oded: Ohh. yes you are right this will fail if we want post read by a user. It will add more complexity in this task. :-(

Comment: @Harry - The query you are suggesting will be rather expensive. And `IN` will not work on a comma separated string in most databases.

Comment: @Oded: I don't know much about it. But i think you may be right and my solution will not become the right one to be selected for this problem. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design seems like the right one.

You can perhaps consider an expiration for this functionality - that is, any post that is over a week old (or whatever) can be expunged from this table (either archive it or not).

Or a maximum of 10 unread posts per user...

Comment: I think I would stick to my initial design. And any posts >100 days are considered as archived and will be shown as read. So, any posts <100 days and not had an entry in read_posts table would be shown as unread.

Answer (score 1):

You can somehow try to compress the information somehow. You need to show the user if he has read a post, only if the user logs on, so you should store the information somewhere near the user. The user might look throught your posts in a date sorted way, so read-post-information of nearly dates should ly nearby, for efficient caching and reading of many values.

Try a table with this stucture:

- user_id
- postmonth
- readposts_array

Depending on how many posts you expect, you might use week or day instead of month. If you cache the value in your app, you might see a performance increase when displaying many posts.

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting a non-normalized column that needs to be queried on?

Comment: No, it does not. You query on postmonth, and hope to get a bunch of read posts on this month. I just assumed that doing 10 queries to the database for 10 posts might be reduced to doing maybe 3 queries and having to look through an array. Might be faster, and I would try it, but it depends headyly on the usage pattern.

Answer (score 0):

For each user you could store the greatest post_id when they logoff (or at each action that they take).  Then when they return, any posts with an id greater than that are flagged as being new.

It doesn't account for posts that they didn't read on their previous visit, but would give a simple indicator of activity that is new since their last visit.  It would only need an extra column on the users table, so should be relatively low impact.

This assumes that posts have incrementing integers as their ID of course

Comment: @Kirs: But it may happen that user will directly read 10th post without reading first 9 post and logs off. Then what will happen? He will miss the first 9 post.

Comment: As I mention "It doesn't account for posts that they didn't read on their previous visit" - it doesn't fully meet the requirement as stated by OP, of tracking all posts read, but I thought this might be another alternative to consider to quickly flag 'new content since last visit'.  PHPBB appears to work in this manner for instance, although I haven't checked the code / DB for the mechanism used